# Not to select last column in named range vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
With Range("OriginSize")
.RowHeight = 12.75
.ColumnWidth = 3
End With
```

But I do not want last column of this range to be touched. Anybody know ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
With Range("OriginSize").Resize(Range("OriginSize").Rows.Count,Range("OriginSize").Columns.Count-1)
.RowHeight = 12.75
.ColumnWidth = 3
End With
```

Resize (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx) allows you to change the size of a range.